# Optimal tables relationship for rails applications

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, database

Let's assume, I would like to write an application which allows the user to search for cars according different criteria. For example, a user would first know which model are built from a specific car manufacture; or, filters cars according to car manufacture and model.

To achieve this purpose I started to design all the tables that I need in my Db:

- Manufacture
- Model
- Cars

### **Idea A**

Every car model is associated to exactly one car manufacture and one car can only be associated to one model.
[image: Idea A]

**Advantages**
This structure would allow my to easily identify all car models belonging to a specific car manufacture or all cars belonging to a specific car model.

**Disadvantages**
Into the car table there is no direct indication of the car manufacture (only through the car model).

### **Idea B**

Every car is associated to a car manufacture and a model.
[image]

**Advantages**
I can now access to all information of the car without navigate through others tables.

**Disadvantages**
If I want to find all cars associated to a specific model or manufacture, the task looks complicated.

### **My questions**

1. Which is the best strategy? Are there better solutions?
2. Which is from the point of view of collecting data, faster?

Comment: What is a "Car" in your schema?  Is it a physical car, that's been manufactured and is in a showroom somewhere?  Or is it still something a bit abstract?  What's the difference between a Car and a Model, basically?

Comment: BTW, you probably want to be talking about a "Manufacturer" rather than a "Manufacture".  "Manufacture" is a verb, "Manufacturer" is a noun meaning "someone who manufactures".  So Ford, Porsche, etc, might be instances of your Manufacturer class.

Comment: A Car is an object that represent a physical car. Instead a Model just represent the tpye of the car (like Ford Focus, Fiesta, Mondeo, ...) For simplify the question I minimized the attributes of the Car. Of course, others attrubutes like engine, fuel, colour, or horse power could be added. You're right! I should use Manufacturer instead of Manufacture.

Answer (score 0):

I'd stick with your version A, as it more accurately reflects the data you're modelling. Each model is only made by one manufacturer, and if you know the model of car you can immediately infer the manufacturer. With version B, there is no such link.

In terms of the associations within Rails, you can model the relationships easily:

```
class Manufacturer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :models
  has_many :cars, through: :models
end

class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :manufacturer
  has_many :cars
end

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :model
end
```

In terms of directly accessing a car's manufacturer, `@car.model.manufacturer` will of course work, but you can also use the delegate method to be a little more direct:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :model
  delegate :manufacturer, to: :model
end
```

When it comes to searching, Rails will let you get to where you need to go. For example, to find all cars with a manufacturer named 'Ford':

```
Car.joins(:model => :manufacturer).where(manufacturers: { name: 'Ford' })
```

If you need to do any more complex queries, you can include the relevant SQL fragments in your `joins` or `where` calls. If you outgrow ActiveRecord's DB calls and scope chaining, you can explore extensions like [Squeel](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel), or access [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel) directly – but the project you describe should be fine with AR's native calls, at least to begin with.

---

In terms of "collecting data" – your approach B would enable you to build a form using Rails helpers that was able to convert both associations to dropdowns or radio buttons. However, as I say above, you'd lose the accuracy of your data modelling. Have a think about how often you add/remove manufacturers and models – if they are frequently updated, that'll have a big effect on your user interface, compared to a situation where all the manufacturers and models are predefined and rarely change.

Comment: I agree, A is better.  In B, if you want to know which Manufacturer makes a particular model you need to find a car record for that model and look it up from there, which is definitely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
#app/models/car.rb
Class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
   #fields id | manufacturer_id | name | model | other | information | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :manufacturer
end

#app/models/manufacturer.rb
Class Manufacturer < ActiveRecord::Base
   #fields id | name | foundation_year | etc | etc
   has_many :cars
end

#app/models/model.rb
Class Model < Car
   self.inheritance_column = :model # http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods/inheritance_column
   #this uses the Car model to populate different "models". It will allow you to identify the model based on the car - using the same table for all
end
```

You probably don't need a separate table for `Model`, as I would presume a `Car` is a `Model` in itself? Instead, I'd look at using [STI (Single Table Inheritance)](http://blog.thirst.co/post/14885390861/rails-single-table-inheritance) to call any specific models of car based on the model you define:

```
#app/controllers/models_controller.rb
Class ModelsController < ApplicationController
   def show
       @cars = Model.find params[:id]
   end
end
```

You should really use an STI with multiple models (IE having a specific model for each `Model` of your cars). The reason I would recommend against it is because of my presumption that each of your `Car` objects will have a model of its own

If this is not the case, use the recommendation below. However,

---

**Multiple Models**

A simpler way to handle the models / cars is to use a simple association for the models:

```
#app/models/car.rb
Class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
   # fields id | manufacturer_id | name | other | car | details | created_at | updated_at
   has_many :models
   belongs_to :manufacturer
end

#app/models/manufacturer.rb
Class Manufacturer < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :cars
   #fields id | name | foundation_year | other | attributes | created_at | updated_at
end

#app/models/model.rb
Class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
   #fields id | name | wheels | engine | etc | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :car
end
```

This gives you the ability to create different models per "car" - IE have a "sports" version etc.

---

**ActiveRecord**

You'll be best [reading up on ActiveRecord associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#why-associations-questionmark), and the role they play in Rails

You have to consider that **Rails is centred around *objects*** - meaning everything you do has to be modularized as best as possible. If you have a table with multiple attributes for the same object, you're going to run into problems

You need to consider the relationships (associations) between your objects, to the degree that you need to construct your models to reflect how they'll be called. This is vitally important, as currently, you're looking for database setup -- you need to switch focus to **object** setup

Ideally, you want this:

```
@car = Car.find params[:id]
@car.models.each do |model|
   model.name
end
```